# How do you create a VLOOKUP using VBA 7.1?

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I would like to use VBA to update cells in an Excel Worksheet to VLOOKUP values in another worksheet in the same spreadsheet, this is in the likes of:

```
Cells(2, intColNum + 1).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(R[0]C[-1],NameKeyIndex!C:D,2,FALSE)"
```

However, when I run it in VBA, it goes into Excel like this:

```
=VLOOKUP(E3,NameKeyIndex!F:F:D,2,FALSE)
```

If I change it manually in Excel to `C:D` , it works, however is there a way it can **not** change my code and parse it as it is correctly?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using R1C1 notation in your formula, then set it using `FormulaR1C1` (and don't mix A1 and R1C1 within the same formula)

```
Cells(2, intColNum + 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(R[0]C[-1],NameKeyIndex!C3:C4,2,FALSE)"
```

Comment: Ahh Tim, thank you!
I see it now, to keep the same notation (though "mixing it"), I needed to use ```C1:C3``` in place of ```A:C``` , as ```C1:C3``` would return ```$A:$C``` . Long nights... thanks again!